# "Out of local stack" reversing a list

Tags: prolog

I wrote the following Prolog code:

```
concatenate([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]) :- concatenate(L1, L2, L3).
concatenate([], L, L).

rev([X|L], Y) :- concatenate(Z, [X], Y), rev(L, Z).
rev([], []).
```

If I do some queries like:

```
?- rev([1,2,3], [3,2,1]).  ->  true
?- rev([1,2,3], [ X, Y, Z]).  -> X=3, Y=2, Z=1
```

it's ok, but if I do:

```
?- rev([1, 2, 3], X).
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

I'm sure I can find a correct implementation of `reverse function` on the web, but I want to know what does cause this error.

Comment: Not a solution, but you can try printing the value at each of the step to debug the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concatenate(L1, L2, L3).` get called with *both* L1 and L3 not instanced, then loops forever. You can see this behaviour using the debugger: just

```
?- gtrace,rev([1,2,3],X).
```

then request a step inside concatenate (hit the space bar). In top left frame (bindings) you see the instantiated variables: just L2 get a value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
rev([X|L], Y) :- concatenate(Z, [X], Y), rev(L, Z).
```

Try:

```
rev([X|L], Y) :- rev(L, Z), concatenate(Z, [X], Y).
```